# How do you install perl DBD::Oracle on OSX Snow Leopard 10.6

Tags: perl, oracle, macos, osx-snow-leopard, dbd

I'm trying to connect to Oracle 10.2.0.4 on a remote system from my intel mac running OSX 10.6 snow leopard. I've tried using perl CPAN to install DBD::Oracle (DBI worked ok) but get compilation errors. Could someone provide an easy to follow guide?

Comment: If you follow nickistat's recipe and get it working would you mind mailing martin at cpan dot org with the outcome and any changes you made. I will then add it to the README.macosx.txt file in DBD::Oracle. It would be useful to know your exact mac processor and version details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Getting a mac install of perl to play nicely with oracle is a bit of a pain - once it's running it is fantastic, getting it running is a little frustrating..

The below has worked for me on a few different intel macs, there could well be superfluous steps in there and it is likely not going to be the same for other platforms.

This will require use of shell, the root user and a bit of CPANing - nothing too onerous

First off create a directory for the oracle pap - libraries, instant client etc

```
sudo mkdir /usr/oracle_instantClient64
```

Download and extract all 64 bit instant client packages from [oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/intel-macsoft-096467.html) to the above directory

Create a symlink within that directory for one of the files in there

```
sudo cd /usr/oracle_instantClient64
sudo ln -s /usr/oracle_instantClient64/libclntsh.dylib.10.1 libclntsh.dylib
```

The following dir is hardcoded into the oracle instant client - god knows why - so need to create and symlink it

```
sudo mkdir -p /b/227/rdbms/
sudo cd /b/227/rdbms/
sudo ln -s /usr/oracle_instantClient64/ lib
```

Need to add a couple of environment variables, so edit /etc/profile and add them so they exist for all users:

```
export ORACLE_HOME=/usr/oracle_instantClient64
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/oracle_instantClient64
```

Now try and install DBD::Oracle through CPAN - this will fail, but it means any dependencies will be downloaded and it retrieves the module for us

```
sudo perl -MCPAN -e shell
install DBD::Oracle
```

When this fails exit CPAN and head to your .cpan/build dir - if you used automatic config of CPAN it'll be

```
cd ~/.cpan/build
```

if you didn't auto configure you can find your build directory with the following command in CPAN

```
o conf build_dir
```

Once in the build dir look for the DBD::Oracle dir which has just been created (it'll be called something like DBD-Oracle-1.28-?) and cd into it.

Now we need to switch to the root user.  Root isn't enabled as default in osx - for details on enabling see this post on the [apple website](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1528)

Once logged in as root we need to set the above environment variables for root:

```
export ORACLE_HOME=/usr/oracle_instantClient64
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/oracle_instantClient64
```

Now while still logged in as root we need to run the makefile for the module, then make, then install

```
perl Makefile.pl
make
make install
```

Assuming that all worked without error log out of root: we're DBD'd up!  If this didn't work it's time to bust out google on whatever errors you're seeing

Now just to install the DBI module

```
sudo perl -MCPAN -e shell
install DBI
```

Now you're all set - enjoy your perly oracley new life

Additional info from user852637:

1. Correction to this step

   ```
   perl Makefile.pl
   make
   install
   ```

   The last step should be `make install`
2. During make, you may encounter an error that looks like :

   > lipo: can't open input file: /var/tmp//ccIevTzM.out (No such file or directory)

   To correct this you must edit the file "Makefile" created after the "perl Makefile.pl" step and remove all occurrences of the following text :

   ```
   -arch ppc
   ```

   This will eliminate the error.
3. The same error described in (2.) will occur during the installation of the DBI module. You must edit the `Makefile` created after the `perl Makefile.pl` step and remove all occurrences of the following text :

   ```
   -arch ppc
   ```

Comment: That sounds very useful and I notice there is nothing on 10.6 in the readme.macosx.txt with DBD::Oracle. Do you mind if I add it to DBD::Oracle?

Comment: go for it - I've run this process on: Macmini3,1 ; MacPro1,1 ; and an old MacbookPro (not sure what model identifier)

Comment: You can use `look DBD::Oracle` in place of exiting the CPAN shell, finding the build dir, and `cd`ing to it.

Comment: It is way smarter to do this kind of installations in /Aplications instead of in /usr. Think about upgrades of the system ....

Comment: Added to DBD::Oracle readme.macosx.txt and should be in 1.29_1.

Answer (score 4):

It looks with the XCode4 change (removal of PPC arch support) the Perl installation was not updated in any of the 10.6.X updates to also remove PPC binaries (probably because Rosetta is still present).

Because of this, the configuration files retain "-arch ppc" causing all CPAN module compiles with C libraries to fail because MakeMaker's output Makefile contains -arch ppc.

To fix this one can edit the following file:

```
/System/Library/Perl/5.10.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level/Config_heavy.pl
```

at line 1219 you'll see:

```
$archflags = exists($ENV{ARCHFLAGS}) ? $ENV{ARCHFLAGS} : '-arch x86_64 -arch i386 -arch ppc';
```

change that to:

```
$archflags = exists($ENV{ARCHFLAGS}) ? $ENV{ARCHFLAGS} : '-arch x86_64 -arch i386';
```

Once you do this the generated Makefile will be correct.

Comment: Thanks!  Been digging for a good solution for this for a while.

Answer (score 3):

These are a great set of instructions. I have a few other comments about potential "gotchas".

1. Correction to this step

   ```
   perl Makefile.pl
   make
   install
   ```

   The last step should be `make install`
2. During make, you may encounter an error that looks like :

   > lipo: can't open input file: /var/tmp//ccIevTzM.out (No such file or directory)

   To correct this you must edit the file "Makefile" created after the "perl Makefile.pl" step and remove all occurrences of the following text :

   ```
   -arch ppc
   ```

   This will eliminate the error.
3. The same error described in (2.) will occur during the installation of the DBI module. You must edit the `Makefile` created after the `perl Makefile.pl` step and remove all occurrences of the following text :

   ```
   -arch ppc
   ```

Answer (score 1):

It seems as though the "Perl MakeFile.pl" command is not finding the version of Perl correctly and I get this error message:

```
bash-3.2# perl Makefile.PL 
Multiple copies of Driver.xst found in: /Library/Perl/5.10.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/DBI/ /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.10.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/DBI/ at Makefile.PL line 37
Using DBI 1.616 (for perl 5.010000 on darwin-thread-multi-2level) installed in /Library/Perl/5.10.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/DBI/

Configuring DBD::Oracle for perl 5.010000 on darwin (darwin-thread-multi-2level)

Remember to actually *READ* the README file! Especially if you have any problems.

Installing on a darwin, Ver#10.0
Using Oracle in /usr/oracle_instantClient64
Can't find sqlplus. Pity, it would have helped.
I'm having trouble finding your Oracle version number... trying harder

WARNING: I could not determine Oracle client version so I'll just
default to version 8.0.0.0. Some features of DBD::Oracle may not work.
Oracle version based logic in Makefile.PL may produce erroneous results.
You can use "perl Makefile.PL -V X.Y.Z" to specify a your client version.

Oracle version 8.0.0.0 (8.0)
DBD::Oracle no longer supports Oracle client versions before 9.2 
 Try a version before 1.25 for 9 and 1.18 for 8! at Makefile.PL line 175.

I've triple checked that I've downloaded and installed the proper 64-bit drivers from Oracle. I also checked to make sure that I'm running 64-bit Perl.
```

If I force the version number like this:

```
perl MakeFile.pl -V 10.2.0.4
```

It completes, but I receive the error message when running "make":

```
Oracle.c:2267: error: ‘SQLT_BIN’ undeclared (first use in this function)
Oracle.c:2277: error: ‘SQLCS_NCHAR’ undeclared (first use in this function)
Oracle.c:2281: error: ‘SQLT_INT’ undeclared (first use in this function)
Oracle.c:2283: error: ‘OCI_FETCH_PRIOR’ undeclared (first use in this function)
Oracle.c:2287: error: ‘OCI_FETCH_NEXT’ undeclared (first use in this function)
lipo: can't open input file: /var/tmp//ccyIFLPN.out (No such file or directory)
make: *** [Oracle.o] Error 1
```

I realize this is because of the "-arch ppc" argument that needs to be removed from Makefile, but even after removal the removal of all 32-bit references, I still saw the error message.

Running 10.6.8 Snow Leopard with Oracle Driver version 10.2.0.4

I found that the key to this issue was making sure that MakeFile.pl could find the Oracle version.

The problem I ran into was that Safari was downloading the zip files from Oracle.com, but unzipping them and somehow corrupting the library.

Instead, I used a different browser and downloaded all the zip files into one directory. Then I ran the following tar commands:

```
tar -xf instantclient-basic-10.2.0.4.0-macosx-x64.zip 
tar -xf instantclient-sdk-10.2.0.4.0-macosx-x64.zip 
tar -xf instantclient-sqlplus-10.2.0.4.0-macosx-x64.zip
```

The copy all the contents in the folder "instantclient_10_2" to $ORACLE_HOME (set previously)

```
sudo cp -R instantclient_10_2/* $ORACLE_HOME
```

Also, I did not need to edit the Makefile generated by the MakeFile.pl script to remove the "-arch ppc" references.

Answer (score 1):

You should not recreate on your machine the same directory structure as of the client libraries packager.

Don't do `mkdir -p /b/227/rdbms/`

Use MacOSX library header management tools: `otool` and `install_name_tool`

For instance, I have updated the library headers to my deployment architecture:

```
otool -L /usr/oracle_instantclient/11.2.0.3.0-64-bit/libclntsh.dylib.11.1
/usr/oracle_instantclient/11.2.0.3.0-64-bit/libclntsh.dylib.11.1:
    /ade/b/2649109290/oracle/rdbms/lib/libclntsh.dylib.11.1 (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /ade/b/2649109290/oracle/ldap/lib/libnnz11.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 159.1.0)

install_name_tool -id /usr/oracle_instantclient/11.2.0.3.0-64-bit/libclntsh.dylib.11.1 \
              -change /ade/b/2649109290/oracle/ldap/lib/libnnz11.dylib /usr/oracle_instantclient/11.2.0.3.0-64-bit/libnnz11.dylib /usr/oracle_instantclient/11.2.0.3.0-64-bit/libclntsh.dylib.11.1


otool -L /usr/oracle_instantclient/11.2.0.3.0-64-bit/libclntsh.dylib.11.1
/usr/oracle_instantclient/11.2.0.3.0-64-bit/libclntsh.dylib.11.1:
    /usr/oracle_instantclient/11.2.0.3.0-64-bit/libclntsh.dylib.11.1 (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /usr/oracle_instantclient/11.2.0.3.0-64-bit/libnnz11.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 159.1.0)
```

Check all files that come with the Oracle instantclient libraries and fix the path of all dependent libs

```
otool -L adrci
otool -L genezi
otool -L libclntsh.dylib.11.1
otool -L libheteroxa11.dylib
otool -L libnnz11.dylib
otool -L libocci.dylib.11.1
otool -L libociei.dylib
otool -L libocijdbc11.dylib
otool -L libsqlplus.dylib
otool -L libsqlplusic.dylib
otool -L sqlplus
otool -L uidrvci
```

Then, you link your dynamic libraries to the place they're supposed to be.

And you can avoid using that `export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` because you know how to setup your system

```
cd /usr/lib
ln -s ../oracle_instantclient/11.2.0.3.0-64-bit/libclntsh.dylib.11.1 .
ln -s ../oracle_instantclient/11.2.0.3.0-64-bit/libclntsh.dylib.11.1 libclntsh.dylib
ln -s ../oracle_instantclient/11.2.0.3.0-64-bit/libheteroxa11.dylib .
ln -s ../oracle_instantclient/11.2.0.3.0-64-bit/libnnz11.dylib .
ln -s ../oracle_instantclient/11.2.0.3.0-64-bit/libocci.dylib.11.1 .
ln -s ../oracle_instantclient/11.2.0.3.0-64-bit/libocci.dylib.11.1 libocci.dylib
ln -s ../oracle_instantclient/11.2.0.3.0-64-bit/libociei.dylib .
ln -s ../oracle_instantclient/11.2.0.3.0-64-bit/libocijdbc11.dylib .
ln -s ../oracle_instantclient/11.2.0.3.0-64-bit/libsqlplus.dylib .
ln -s ../oracle_instantclient/11.2.0.3.0-64-bit/libsqlplusic.dylib .
```