# Installing DBD::Oracle

Tags: perl, cpan, dbd

I'm trying to follow these instructions for installing DBD::Oracle on a Mac (Snow Leopard 10.6.8): [How do you install perl DBD::Oracle on OSX Snow Leopard 10.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5964999/how-do-you-install-perl-dbdoracle-on-osx-snow-leopard-10-6)

Everything worked fine up until the point where I tried to run

```
perl Makefile.pl
```

When I try to run this command, I receive the following error:

```
Can't open perl script "Makefile.pl": No such file or directory
```

The instructions are a little confusing as to which directory this command should be run from, if that matters. I tried running it from the oracle_instantClient64 directory while logged in as the root user, from the oracle_instantClient64 directory while logged in as a regular user, and from the ~/.cpan/build directory while logged in a regular user. The post seems to imply that the command should be run from the ~/.cpan/build directory when logged in as the root user, but I don't see that directory when logged in as root.

Comment: Go to whatever directory you untarred/zipped the archive for `DBD::Oracle`.  In that directory, there should be a file called `Makefile.PL`.  That's what you want to run.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the right filename. It's *Makefile.PL*. You should run the command from the directory which has the *Makefile.PL*. None of those directories you mentioned have the *Makefile.PL*.

Or, you can just use one of the CPAN clients:

```
% cpan DBD::Oracle
```

The *~/.cpan/build* directory has the distributions that the CPAN module has downloaded. If you haven't used that module to fetch the distribution, you won't find the distribution there.